# Django Models: aggregate filter

Tags: python, django, django-models

In my view I get points_total, however it returns all points unlike points_list which filters by the current user.

**Question:**

1) How do I filter 'def points_total' by user like in 'points_list'

**model.py**

```
class PointsManager(models.Manager):

    def points_list(self,thisUser):
        list = Points.objects.filter(user=thisUser)
        return list

    def points_total(self,thisUser):
        return Points.objects.aggregate(models.Sum('points'))


class Points (models.Model):

    statusOptions = (
        (0, 'Pending'),
        (1, 'Added'),
        (2, 'Deducted'),
        (3, 'Processing'),
        )

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    points = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=("Points"), default=0)
    created = models.DateTimeField(("Created at"), auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=("Updated at"), auto_now=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(default=0, choices=statusOptions)

    objects = PointsManager()



    class Meta:
      verbose_name = ('Point')
      verbose_name_plural = ('Points')
```

Comment: Do you want to calculate the points, specific for a user or you want all users with their points total count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I don't think you required a manager for both of your functions, You can achieve directly by querying on the model it self.

Alternative for `point_list` function

```
points_list = Points.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

Alternative for `points_total` function

```
points = Points.objects.filter(user=request.user) \
                       .aggregate(total_points=models.Sum('points'))
```

Comment: you second code sample works in my models.py. could you explain how I can achieve it directly by querying on the model it self as you suggested?

Comment: the code which I have posted is not using any manager. So this is as i suggested. You have to remove the manager.